# How can I use Java 11 repeat() method in a Method reference?

Tags: java, string, functional-programming, method-reference, functional-interface

```
public class X{
    public static void print(Integer n, Function<Integer, String> fn) {
        System.out.println(fn.apply(n));
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        print(3, Integer::repeat()); //
     }
}
```

*Example*:

Since `3` is a given number, the value returned by the *function* and printed on the console should be `"aaa"`.

Comment: There is no method `repeat()` in class [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html). If there were, `Integer::repeat()` should be `Integer::repeat`.

Comment: Why would you want to?  `String.repeat` takes two arguments a `String` to repeat and a `count`.   A `BiFunction` takes two arguments, a `String` to repeat and a `count`.

Answer (score 4):

Your method reference is wrong in a couple ways.  First, a method reference doesn't end in parentheses `()`.  Second, the `Integer` class doesn't have any `repeat` method.

The [`String` class defines the `repeat` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)), available for the first time in Java 11.  But you want to execute on a specific instance of a string, namely the constant `"a"`.

Try `"a"::repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

*Method references* as well as *lambda expressions* should conform to a *function interface*, by providing an implementation of the *abstract method* defined by this interface.

And interface `Function` declares a method [`apply()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#apply(T))

```
R apply(T t);
```

You can implement it like that with lambda expression:

```
Function<Integer, String> fun = num -> String.valueOf(num);
```

Method `repeat()` is an instance method of the `String` class, i.e. you have to invoke it on the instance of the `String`. So, need to define this string either by outside the lambda or hard-code it inside the body of lambda.

```
public static final String str = "a";

Function<Integer, String> fun = num -> str.repeat(num);
```

Now, in order to transform this *lambda expression* in a *method reference*, let's first pose the question of what the *method reference* is.

**Method reference** - is the way to utilize an existing method to provide an  implantation of the behavior defined by a *function interface*.

There are ***four kinds of method references*** (a quote from the [*Oracles's tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)):

- Reference to a static method `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type `ContainingType::methodName`
- Reference to a constructor `ClassName::new`

***Note** that the syntax of *method references* doesn't require parentheses* `()` *because that how the language was designed, and I guess because method references are intended to be concise and expressive.*

The type of method reference that we need to implement this function using `repeat()` method is a *reference to an instance method of a particular object* (because `repeat()` is an instance method). And that's how it might look like:

```
public static final String str = "a";

Function<Integer, String> fun = str::repeat;

print(3, fun); // or print(3, str::repeat);
```

***Note*** that variables used inside both method references and lambda expressions must be final or effectively final, i.e. should be assigned only once.